# Are people who have a closer unity to God called to act by the divine?

Tags: philosophy, spirituality

It seems from observation that one of the hallmark signs of a higher being (one that is in close unity with the divine with respect to their actions and thoughts) is that they tend to have a transcendental instinct for meaning and life in general, where the typical man whose disjoint with the divine tends to act either rationally or impulsively, the transcendental instinct of the higher being provides him a certain spiritual realm with a degree of psychic ability—ability to decipher danger, ability to decipher accurately between good and evil, making inferences that cannot be deduced by logic and by method. It seems that the higher being is called to their actions rather than them acting solely based on a sequence of deterministic causes. A certain type of free will with a transcendental basis..

Comment: This appears to me to be a question about philosophy, not about Christianity. An edit, I would suggest, is needed to bring it within topic.

Comment: @NigelJ thank you

Comment: I don't recognise anything that you're saying here as having any connection to what any Christian denominations teach. Do you have any Christian sources that support your statement "one of the hallmark signs of a higher being (one that is in close unity with the divine with respect to their actions and thoughts) is that they tend to have a transcendental instinct for meaning and life in general"?

Comment: Hope to have an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

From the Christian context, all believers are called to act by God (the divine) regardless of their level of spiritual maturity:

Matthew 22:36-40
King James Version

> 36 Master, which is the great commandment in the law?
> 37 Jesus said unto him, Thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy mind.
> 38 This is the first and great commandment.
> 39 And the second is like unto it, Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself.
> 40 On these two commandments hang all the law and the prophets.

These commands are not to avoid doing something -- such as "thou shalt not", but are commands to pro-actively do Love.

It is only humans that are respecters of persons:

James 2:1-5
King James Version

> My brethren, have not the faith of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Lord of glory, with respect of persons.
> 2 For if there come unto your assembly a man with a gold ring, in goodly apparel, and there come in also a poor man in vile raiment;
> 3 And ye have respect to him that weareth the gay clothing, and say unto him, Sit thou here in a good place; and say to the poor, Stand thou there, or sit here under my footstool:
> 4 Are ye not then partial in yourselves, and are become judges of evil thoughts?
> 5 Hearken, my beloved brethren, Hath not God chosen the poor of this world rich in faith, and